Prevent shadow from being clipped when using overflow-y-auto
I'm using overflow-y-auto here so that I can scroll when there are too many items and the browser shrinks vertically:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="border-border flex max-h-[calc(100vh-7.5rem)] w-full flex-col items-start justify-start gap-0 overflow-y-auto rounded border p-3 md:max-w-64 md:border-none md:p-0">
  <span>Item 1</span>
  <span>Item 2</span>
  <button class="border-border ring-foreground text-foreground bg-secondary hover:shadow-dark flex h-10 w-full items-center justify-center gap-2 text-nowrap rounded border px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium shadow ring-offset-2 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 md:w-auto">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="tabler-icon tabler-icon-folder-plus h-4 w-4 shrink-0">
      <path d="M12 19h-7a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-11a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h4l3 3h7a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v3.5"></path>
      <path d="M16 19h6"></path>
      <path d="M19 16v6"></path></svg
    >Create category
  </button>
</div>



This is clipping the shadow of the button:

Tailwind Playground
What's the best way to prevent this?

I can indeed see in the Tailwind playground that it's cut off, although it suddenly appears when zooming in, but it always displays correctly in the SO snippet.

Got it. I set the min-height to the same value, and it worked. The problem with the max-height is that the shadow isn’t counted towards the height. I think you should add padding to the element, and the max-height will be fine (this is the issue, not the overflow).

The added code-snippet is misleading because you have the proper padding below the md screen size, but not above it. In any case, I didn't want to interfere with your code.

You set a maximum height. This means that until the element reaches the maximum value, the parent div will be exactly as tall as its content determines. The bottom of the button will mark the end of the height. The shadow isn’t included in this. Add some padding.
To notice the difference, zoom in both snippets to full screen (md screen size recommended).


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="border-border flex max-h-[calc(100vh-7.5rem)] w-full flex-col items-start justify-start gap-0 overflow-y-auto rounded border p-3 md:max-w-64 md:border-none md:p-0 md:pb-3">
  <span>Item 1</span>
  <span>Item 2</span>
  <button class="border-border ring-foreground text-foreground bg-secondary hover:shadow-dark flex h-10 w-full items-center justify-center gap-2 text-nowrap rounded border px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium shadow ring-offset-2 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 md:w-auto">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="tabler-icon tabler-icon-folder-plus h-4 w-4 shrink-0">
      <path d="M12 19h-7a2 2 0 0 1 -2 -2v-11a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2h4l3 3h7a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v3.5"></path>
      <path d="M16 19h6"></path>
      <path d="M19 16v6"></path></svg
    >Create category
  </button>
</div>



Tailwind Playground
